# Javascript - Class - Method Returning Undefined When Calling Constructor Property

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning Javascript. When I run the following code, I am getting undefined. Not sure what is wrong. Everything seems to be fine. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
class User{
  constructor(){
    this.array = [1, 2, 3]
  }

  static getNumber(){
    return console.log(this.array)
    
  }
}


User.getNumber()
```

Comment: A static method doesn't have access to instance properties.

Comment: This is javascript, not java.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you that was it. So the only way to access the instance is by removing the static?

Comment: @user1280483 Well, this wouldn't work in any OOP language... neither in Java

Comment: You can paste this code into any modern javascript console/site and have it run- and the result is, as expected, `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to create a new instance of `User` with `new User()` or `new User` if you want to be able to access instance properties (such as `array`), because they are created with `this.array = ...`. From the Mozilla Web Docs:

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class, or
> a class static initialization block (see the link for more information
> about this usage). Neither static methods nor static properties can be
> called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class
> itself.
>
> Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to
> create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for
> caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be
> replicated across instances.

Because `getNumber` is called on the constructor itself, it doesn't have access to any of the instance properties (the only one is `this.array`). When `new User` is called, it creates the `this.array`, but only for the instance, not the constructor.